# wget 302 Moved Temporarily in bash shell script

Tags: bash, sed, wget

I have a bash script that takes a url from a html file using `grep | sed` and putting it into a variable. Then that variable (piece of url) is concatenated with the domain and send a `wget` http get request. As result I'm getting a `302 moved temporarily` result, I haven't taking a look at some people with this issue, mostly talk about the quotes or double quotes characters, the issue is that event putting quotes or double quotes still response the same.

Here part of the script

```
var='http://domain.com'
var+=`grep "class='some class'" file.html | sed -E "s/^.+href='([^']+)'.+$/\1/"`
wget "$var"
```

Comment: wont the wget following the 302 redirection?

Comment: A 302 response code does not necessarily mean there is a problem.  I just means that you should access the resource using a different URL which will be provided in the response.

Comment: That `grep | sed` can be rewritten as just `sed -E "/class='some class'/s/^.+href='([^']+)'.+$/\1/"`.